# Disallow any incoming connection but allow the only added iptables rules

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I want to disallow any incoming connection from any IP address except for those who are allowed in an iptables rule like that:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -s 147.0.0.0 --dport 5566 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 25 -j REJECT
```

This will allow 147.0.0.0 to connect through 5566 with only 25 max concurrent connections. So I want only `147.0.0.0` to access the server and disallow any other because `147.0.0.0` is added in this iptables rule.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using ufw (Uncomplicated Firewall)? It's much easier to use than hand crafting iptables yourself, and you can edit the ufw rules config to provide extra functionality beyond the simple interface. To add concurrent connection limits as you want, you can follow this link https://florent.clairambault.fr/limiting-number-of-connections-per-ip-with-ufw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note before: You might need to allow some other things in for your computer to work properly. For example: Port 53, DNS stuff; Ports 67 and 68, DHCP stuff; Local loopback stuff.

Something like this might be what you are looking for:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -s 147.0.0.0 --dport 5566 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 25 -j REJECT
sudo iptables -A INPUT REJECT
```

It allows local loopback interface stuff and will allow back replies to stuff that you initiated out.